# Install metabase using nssm and Inno Setup script

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascalscript, metabase, nssm

I want to open an administrative CMD window using Inno Setup and want to install:

```
nssm install metabase
```

I tried the following function, but it doesn't work.

```pascal
Exec(ExpandConstant('{cmd}'), ' nssm install', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
```

Please someone help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: 1. You don't need `ExpandConstant('{cmd}')` to run a command (and you'd need `/c` after it anyway). 2. What's the path to `nssm`?

Comment: nssm path is windows/system32.

Comment: So do `Exec('nssm', 'install', ...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are effectively executing:

```
cmd nssm install
```

That wouldn't work anywhere, not only in Inno Setup. It should be:

```
cmd /c nssm install
```

Though, it's an overkill to run `nssm` via `cmd`. Run it directly:

```
nssm install
```

In Inno Setup Pascal Script:

```pascal
Exec('nssm', 'install', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
```